# Increase Excel file reading speed

Tags: c#, excel, uwp

I currently use `ExcelDataReader` library to read some excel files and use the data to create a massive object.

https://github.com/ExcelDataReader/ExcelDataReader

What I currently do is .. :

```cs
public static async Task<Poste> ReadData(string posteNumber)
{
    Poste poste = null;

    using (var stream = await posteFile.OpenStreamForReadAsync())
    {
        using (var reader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateReader(stream))
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                string code = reader.GetValue(2) as string;
                if(code != null)
                    if (code.Replace(" ", string.Empty).Equals(posteNumber.Replace(" ", string.Empty)))
                    {
                        poste = new Poste();

                        poste.CodePoste = reader.GetValue(2)?.ToString();
                        poste.Denomination = reader.GetValue(3)?.ToString();
                        poste.Constructeur = reader.GetValue(27)?.ToString();
                        poste.DateMiseEnService = reader.GetValue(23)?.ToString();
                        poste.DateMiseHorsService = reader.GetValue(14)?.ToString();
                        poste.Etat = reader.GetValue(6)?.ToString();
                        poste.Exploitant = reader.GetValue(13)?.ToString();
                        poste.LibelleCommune = reader.GetValue(4)?.ToString();
                        poste.Nature = reader.GetValue(7)?.ToString();
                        poste.CodeSchema = reader.GetValue(20)?.ToString();
                        poste.TypeBatiment = reader.GetValue(8)?.ToString();
                        poste.CodeTournee = reader.GetValue(15)?.ToString();
                        poste.Acces = reader.GetValue(24)?.ToString();
                        poste.Tmni = reader.GetValue(12)?.ToString();
                        poste.Adresse = reader.GetValue(33)?.ToString();
                        poste.Coord.Latitude = reader.GetValue(34)?.ToString();
                        poste.Coord.Longitude = reader.GetValue(35)?.ToString();

                        if (poste.CodePoste != null)
                        {
                            await GetTFMData(posteNumber, poste);
                            await GetDLDData(posteNumber, poste);
                            await GetAMMData(posteNumber, poste);
                            await GetCompteurData(posteNumber, poste);
                            await GetHTAData(posteNumber, poste);
                            await GetBTData(posteNumber, poste);
                        }
                    }
            }
        }
    }
    return poste;
}
```

`CurrentPoste` is a data binded object so I "need" to copy my `Poste` like that if I want to keep the data binding.

It works but takes a very long time to extract the right data from it (~30 sec) and I don't know what to do to optimize that part of my code.

I'm wondering if it's a good idea to put the whole data into a `DataSet` and then read it to extract the data I want from it.

PS : the GetTFMData(posteNumber, poste), await GetDLDData(posteNumber, poste), ... do basically the same thing and are as long as the one I posted.

Comment: The part that reads everything in memory is `AsDataset()`. Don't use that extension if you don't really want a DataSet. Use `reader.NextResult()` to get to the worksheet you want and `reader.Read()` to read rows one by one. Replace every `row[..]` call with `reader.GetValue()`

Comment: The readme says "The AsDataSet() extension method is a convenient helper for quickly getting the data" so I tought it would have been faster to do that.
Because the fact is that I still need to read every row[2] to see if it matches the right number and then get the values of that row

Comment: Which it does by loading everything in memory first. You're loading everytghint in memory and enumerating over the same data twice, when all you needed to do is read only the third column in each sheet and return only the row you wanted as soon as you find it

Comment: Oh yeah, that's right, I'll not use it then.

Comment: When it says "quickly getting the data" it may have meant "quick to code", not "quick to run".

Comment: Oh, I didn't understood it that way

Answer (score 3):

With every single row you're executing this:

```
PropertyInfo[] properties = res.GetType().GetProperties();
```

You're doing reflection to get the properties of whatever type `res` is. Reflection isn't slow enough that we should avoid it at all costs, but we should avoid *repeating* it unnecessarily.

Every single time you get the properties for `res` the result - the list of properties - will be the same. So why do it more than once? Instead, create `properties` once and then reuse it as you populate an object from each row.

You can go a step further. Instead of getting the properties and then inspecting them to see which are writable over and over with each row you write, include that up front:

```
var properties = res.GetType().GetProperties()
    .Where(property => property.CanWrite);
```

Comment: I'm taking your comment, but I think you misunderstood something (the first piece of code isn't really clear, I must admit).
What I do is that I read the Excel files and I'm extracting **one** object from `ReadData()`, so I'm only doing one reflection to copy the properties to the `CurrentPoste`.
I don't want to offend you, maybe it's me who misunderstood your comment.